# Using AJAX in django

Tags: ajax, django

I am new to AJAX and django.

I have written my own `XMLHttpRequest` call on browser side. I will have to manually set the header `request.META['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` to string `XMLHttpRequest`.

How can I access these headers on browser side?

Answer (score 3):

Use `HttpRequest.is_ajax()`. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax).

Answer (score 0):

Some post about django and ajax: [Django AJAX Tutorial Part 1 - adding email to newsletter](http://fromzerotocodehero.blogspot.com/2011/01/django-ajax-tutorial-part-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy to use solution for impolementing ajax ni django, I would recommend [dajax](http://www.dajaxproject.com/) i am using it in my own project and it simplifies things a lot.

of cause you wont be able to customize it as much as with your own programming but especially for beginners its pretty useful